# OpenGL Texture still interpolated even with GL_NEAREST

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, interpolation

I'm making a 3d game using OpenGL and I have encountered a problem I can't find the answer to. For some reason, when I load the textures it is still interpolated.

My image loading:

```cpp
glGenTextures(1, &chunkTex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, chunkTex);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

int width, height, chan;

stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);

unsigned char *data = stbi_load("res/images/atlas.png", &width, &height, &chan, 0);
if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
} else {
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}

stbi_image_free(data);
```

My vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 aPos;
in vec3 aColor;
in vec3 aNormal;
in vec2 uv;

uniform mat4 mvp;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 puv;
out vec3 pNormal;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    puv = uv;
    pNormal = aNormal;
}
```

My fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 col;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 puv;
in vec3 pNormal;

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform vec3 lightDir;

void main()
{
    col = texture(tex, puv) * max(dot(pNormal, -lightDir), 0.1);
}
```

If you could help me fix this I would appreciate it!

Edit: Here are my window hints:

```cpp
glfwInit();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif
```

Comment: Yes of course, the mipmaps are interpolated. See [`Mip Mapping`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mip_Mapping). Use `GL_NEAREST` instead of `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST`.

Comment: "*GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST*" If you don't want interpolation, why do you generate interpolated mipmaps and then select the nearest one?

Comment: Oh thats what that means

Comment: Nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you create a nex texture object and set the texture parameters for it:

```
glGenTextures(1, &chunkTex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, chunkTex);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

But here you unbind it and bind texture object 0 instead:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

and load the texture image to that one:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Now, in legacy and compatibility profile GL, texture object 0 even exists (actually, there even do exist different texture objects named `0` for different texture types), and is usable. But for that one, you never have set the texture filters and will use the default ones. And it looks like you keep textur eobject 0 bound also for rendering, and not the (empty and incomplete) `chunkTex` one.

Comment: when I am rendering I use glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, chunkTex);

Comment: Also when I remove the glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); everything turns black

Comment: @GrigoriIakimenko: Well, the code as posted in your question clearly has the issue I described in my answer. So the full code you're using has either some additional issue(s), or the code you posted doesn't reflect your actual code, or both.  And no matter which of this is actually the case, this is not debuggable from the information given in the question - that's why it is important to post a [minimal, _reproducible_ example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: When I am drawing my texture I actualy had to use chunkTex - 1 for some reason and now it works.

Comment: "For some reason"? It's highly likely that your first texture ID will be `1`, so it is very apparent what this reason might be.